# Why does kotlin/native hello world not output anything inside IntelliJ IDEA on Apple M1?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-native

I've downloaded a fresh IntelliJ IDEA with the Kotlin multiplatform plugin and created a project using the Native application project template. This template creates a `Main.kt` file with the content:

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello, Kotlin/Native!")
}
```

As well as many other gradle files referencing `kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.7.20"`. I can build and run the project from inside IntelliJ IDEA, but I see no hello world:

[image: no hello world]

I can only see the gradle output and a success result, but no `Hello Kotlin/Native!` message anywhere. I've tried changing the `runDebugExecutableNative` settings and checked the options related to show the console/output when stdout messages are printed:

[image: project settings]

I can see no other output window/pane, so… where can I see the output? The project builds a debug or release `Kasha.kexe` which I can run from the command line manually, but I'm guessing an IDE shouldn't require me to run commands from the command line every time?

```
$ ./build/bin/native/debugExecutable/Kasha.kexe
Hello, Kotlin/Native!
```

I can see a greyed out symbol in the run pane, which corresponds to the output `> Task :runDebugExecutableNative SKIPPED`. Does that mean the IDE can only build but not run the executable? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition) and `kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.7.20"`.

**UPDATE** As [bppleman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292713/why-does-kotlin-native-hello-world-not-output-anything-inside-intellij-idea/74311410#74311410) correctly guesses the problem is I'm trying to run this on an Apple M1 machine. The gradle that comes out from the template is:

```
kotlin {
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }
…
```

Replacing the `macosX64` call with `macosArm64` makes everything work as expected. But I guess now intel based apple machines will be on the wrong side of the fence?

Comment: Did you check this issue? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-51196?_gl=1*1eu1amm*_ga*NTczNTkxNTI0LjE2Njc0MDc0MTM.*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY2NzQwNzQxMy4xLjAuMTY2NzQwNzQxMy4wLjAuMA..&_ga=2.254059016.1868144078.1667407413-573591524.1667407413

Comment: I cannot reproduce on IntelliJ CE 2021.2.4 and Kotlin 1.7.

Comment: @GerardV @Sweeper I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition) and `kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.7.20"`.

Comment: check your run configuration - it looks like you're running the gradle task `runDebugExectuableNative`  - try just using the play button to the left of your main function in the gutter. :)

Comment: @bsautner the gutter play button simply runs the `runDebugExecutableNative` gradle task.

Comment: I failed to reproduce the problem. Can you attach a link to your project?

Comment: You can check if (System.getProperty("os.arch") == "aarch64") macosArm64("native") else macosX64("native")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see a new edit to the question

> Replacing the macosX64 call with macosArm64 makes everything work as expected. But I guess now intel based apple machines will be on the wrong side of the fence?

So I'll submit a new answer to that question

Indeed, as you said, there will still be problems after switching to intel mac, so my approach is to judge the current cpu platform at the same time, just like this

```kotlin
val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
val isMingw = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
val nativeTarget = when {
    hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> {
        if (System.getProperty("os.arch").contains("aarch64")) {
            macosArm64("native")
        } else {
            macosX64("native")
        }
    }
    hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
    isMingw -> {
        if (System.getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)") != null) {
            mingwX86("native")
        } else {
            mingwX64("native")
        }
    }
    else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
}
```

Of course you can also do this, it depends on your needs

```kotlin
kotlin {
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTargets = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> listOf(macosArm64("native"), macosX64("macosX64"))
        hostOs == "Linux" -> listOf(linuxX64("native"))
        isMingwX64 -> listOf(mingwX64("native"))
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    nativeTargets.forEach { target ->
        target.apply {
            binaries {
                executable {
                    entryPoint = "main"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val nativeMain by getting
        val nativeTest by getting
        val macosX64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(nativeMain)
        }
        val macosX64Test by getting {
            dependsOn(nativeTest)
        }
    }
}
```

Use dependsOn to share sourceSet.

It is important to note that there can only be one executeabl entry between two macOS sourceSets

[image]

You should not add another entry for macosX64 unless you really want to, then you have to remove the dependsOn dependency

u'll got:

[image]

Comment: How is it possible that Intellij doesnt do this by default??? Many thanks for this!

Comment: For me it did do it by default, but broke so many other things that I had to start from scratch and lose this part… good one, thanks.