# Kotlin Native project builds but doesn't run from IntelliJ IDEA on M1 Mac after reinstalling ("runDebugExecutableNative SKIPPED")

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, build, apple-m1, kotlin-native

I've had IntelliJ IDEA on my M1 Mac but only really used it when I wanted to learn Kotlin Native, and started a small commandline project about a month ago.

I switched to building and editing outside IntelliJ IDEA, which still works.

Later I completely uninstalled all my IntelliJ software including Toolbox and Android Studio to get some other problem solved. I kept my projects.

I just reinstalled the latest IntelliJ IDEA (2022.3.2 Community Edition, no Toolbox this time) and now the Kotlin Native project builds but does not run from the IDE. It still builds and runs from the commandline (Using `./gradlew`).

Basically it does the build step whether I hit the Build button or the Run button on the IDE. Before reinstalling the Run button used to run it.

When I hit the Run button it builds and tells me everything worked. No error message but there is this note output: `runDebugExecutableNative SKIPPED`.

Even though I wasn't using the IntelliJ stuff much I was keeping it updated. But perhaps there was a missed update between when I uninstalled it and when I reinstalled it a few days later that made something not work??

---

Some things I've found:

1. In the Run/Debug Configurations screen I seem to have something broken, with a little red cross. I don't know what this used to look like before reinstalling IDEA.
   [image: little red cross]
2. When I select that configuration, at the bottom there's an error message: `Error: No main class specified`. I don't remember if I had to specify a main class when I started the project.
   [image: no main class error]

Comment: Can you click `...` in `Run/Debug Configurations dialog > Main Class` input? It may search and find the latest main class entry.

Comment: @ocos under "Search by name" it thinks for a couple of seconds and says `No matches found`. Under "Project" I click all through the tree of files in my project, but nowhere does the `OK` button stop being disabled.

Comment: So, find your `main()` function and hover your mouse over it. It will show something `com.example.ApplicationKt` assuming that your main in Application.kt file. Type this into main class input. Otherwise just clean the build or invalidate IntelliJ caches.

Comment: Hovering over main I see `kt-wiktionary.nativeMain` which gives the error `Warning: Class 'kt-wiktionary.nativeMain' not found in module 'kt-wiktionary'`. I also tried deleting and rearranging the parts of that string to no avail. I'll try cleaning now and if that doesn't work I'll try invalidating the caches. I didn't see 'clean' but 'rebuild' made no difference. Neither did invalidating the default caches. Now trying with invalidating all the optional caches too.

Comment: Still no difference after invalidating all caches.

Comment: I did not pay attention that it was kotlin native. Forget about that dialog. In Gradle Window, there is `run > runDebugExecutableNative`. Can you try it or you should be able to run from the gutter icon near the `main()` method.

Comment: @ocos When I click the little green triangle next to `main()` it seems to build and not even try to run. Output ends with `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 876ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
12:58:20 pm: Execution finished 'runDebugExecutableNative'.` UPDATE I just noticed it also says `> Task :compileKotlinNative UP-TO-DATE
> Task :linkDebugExecutableNative UP-TO-DATE
> Task :runDebugExecutableNative SKIPPED`

Comment: This reminds me that I had a problem setting up the project originally and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292713) I think was the one that led me to edit a config file to manually set my system to M1. I know that's still set because it still builds from the commandline. But maybe there is another place I also have to change that now?

Comment: At least you should have an executable in `./build/bin/native/debugExecutable/native.kexe`. It's best to give a try to other SO answer. Sorry could not help much.

Comment: The Kotlin native project doesn't use the Kotlin Application run configuration. It uses the Gradle run configuration to build and run it. The native project generated by IDEA doesn't support M1 and [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-18891/) will be fixed in a later version so the `runDebugExecutableNative` task is skipped. Try a workaround [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-18891/Support-Apple-Silicon-Mac-M1-Arm-in-Kotlin-Native-new-project-wizard#focus=Comments-27-6535230.0-0) and the gutter run should works.

Comment: @LJreplica: I think I had to do that when I first had to set up the project. I still have have `hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosArm64("native")` in my `build.gradle.ktx` and it builds and runs fine from the commandline with `./gradlew build` which I guess uses the .ktx file. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If not, when you build the project, can you check if the `.kexe` file was created at the location @ocos mentioned?

Comment: Oh ok. If I create a new Kotlin/Native project then and run `main()` as you did, the `.kexe` file is built but doesn't run. I also see `runDebugExecutableNative SKIPPED`. As a workaround, I created a run configuration in the IDE that executes a shell script to run the file after building it.

Comment: @JustTheHighlights: I apologize! My previous comments from the last day or so are wrong. I never resolved this problem. I got the wrong impression because I'm working on the same toy project in ten or so languages and when I fired up IntelliJ IDEA to check when you asked I failed to notice that it opened the Java version automatically. I just noticed and checked the Kotlin version and it still builds and runs fine from the commandline but only builds and does not run from the IDE. I'll go back and delete my wrong responses.

Comment: No worries. Okay you should consider raising a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project:%20%7BIDEA%7D

Comment: Guess what? I only just saw the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292713/) that was linked above. That solution worked for me. i.e. changing `macosX64("native")` to `macosArm64("native")` to work on M1 macs 

Comment: @JustTheHighlights sadly I already have `hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosArm64("native")` on my Mac, which I think I got from a previous problem, but this problem wasn't fixed by it.

Comment: Damn ok. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition) so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm now using 2023.1 (Community Edition). I don't use it often but always update it when I do.

Comment: I found another empty old project I had once started and had the same problem that it built but skipped the run step but in its case changing the line to `macosArm64("native")` did fix it. The `build.gradle.kts` of each project is now identical. Whether I build or rebuild it still skips running. I don't know if there's a deeper way to clean out cruft than just "rebuild"... Even more annoyingly, if I copy and paste the source from the broken project into the other one it does work. I really hate nondeterministic problems like this!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does kotlin/native hello world not output anything inside IntelliJ IDEA on Apple M1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292713/why-does-kotlin-native-hello-world-not-output-anything-inside-intellij-idea-on-a)

Comment: @valbaca: Nope. It's even mentioned in two of my old comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75562947/kotlin-native-project-builds-but-doesnt-run-from-intellij-idea-on-m1-mac-after?noredirect=1#comment134038673_75562947 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75562947/kotlin-native-project-builds-but-doesnt-run-from-intellij-idea-on-m1-mac-after?noredirect=1#comment134038673_75562947